# Can one always extend a smooth section defined on a non compact submanifold to the whole manifold, provided it extends continuously to the closure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $V \rightarrow M$ be a smooth vector bundle over a smooth compact manifold $M$ 
(without boundary) and $X \subset M$ a smooth submanifold of $M$, that is not necessarily closed. 
Suppose $s: X \rightarrow V$ is a smooth section, that extends continuously to 
$\bar{X}$, the closure of $X$ inside $M$. Does there always exist a smooth section 
$\tilde{s}: M \rightarrow V$, that restricted to $\bar{X}$ is equal to $s$?

Note that, if I replaced the word smooth with continuous the answer is yes. We can 
construct such a section using a continuous partition of unity and using the compactness 
of $\bar{X}$. And similarly, if $X$ was compact then there exists a smooth extension 
of $s$, this time using a smooth partition of unity and also using the compactness of $X$.

Comment: In this formulation, the answer in general is not. For instance, if you have a smooth function on $(0, + \infty)$ that extends continuously at $0$, then it fails to be smooth in a neighborhood of $0$ in general (this is the case of a trivial $\Bbb R$-bundle). You must assume in advance smooth extension.

Comment: What is $M$ in your example? I said $M$ must be compact. And I also meant $M$ has no boundary (although I didn't say that clearly). 

Comment: @Ritwik: To flesh out Daniele Zuddas' example, you may take $M=S^1$ consisting of the unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $X$ to be the subset of $M$ consisting of vectors with positive first coordinate.

Comment: Take $M$ to be the circle realized as the 1-point compactification of the real line, $X=(0,\infty)$ and the function 
$s(x)=\sqrt{x}e^{-x}$.  

Comment: Thank you for the examples. I think I understand the argument now 
and realize that the answer to my question can not possibly be yes as stated.